# Dynamics 365: create multiselect field bounded to Entity View

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to customize Sales 365. I need a field in a Lead form to multiselect items from Account View.
Is there any way to do it without coding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a field but you can have a subgrid, relationship between Lead and Account will be N:N, in this way the user can select multiple records from the Account entity.